# Cyclic dependency between Packer and Terraform for non-default VPC

Tags: terraform, packer

My deployment workflow is first creating ami with Packer, then deploy using Terraform.

I have a EC2-class, which was created before 2013, so there's no default VPC configured.

When I run `packer build packer.json`, the tool complains that

```
    amazon-ebs: Adding tag: "Name": "Packer Builder"
==> amazon-ebs: Error launching source instance: VPCResourceNotSpecified: The specified instance type can only be used in a VPC. A subnet ID or network interface ID is required to carry out the request.
==> amazon-ebs:     status code: 400, request id: 35ca5736-f808-4bb9-9a34-3dca24b59259
```

I was planning to create VPC with Terraform. So the question is, what is the order of execution? Run Terraform first, then Packer. Or run in reverse order? Or, we split out the network configuration (VPC), use Terraform to deploy it once, then followed by Packer, and then terraform the rest of the servers?

Update:
If I use the strategy: 
run Network module (mostly static things), followed by Packer, and then run "Frequently changing things" module, how do I share state between Terraform and Packer? Meaning, once I created a new VPC, how do I let Packer know about this new vpc_id? Do I need to modify every Packer file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general advice is to split the terraform configuration into reasonable sized parts.

For a small setup it's reasonable is to split it into *mostly static things* (VPC, subnet, routes, etc). *Frequently changing things* (EC2, SG, etc). This would also solve your dependency cycle.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. How do TF and Packer shares states if I created a new VPC?

Comment: No sure I follow, Packer doesn't have a state?

Comment: For example, after creating a new vpc & subnet with Terraform, I got a new vpc_id and subnet_id. How do I pass this information to Packer json file?

Comment: See `var` and `var-file` arguments to the `build` command. https://www.packer.io/docs/commands/build.html